# Leak Sanitizer gives too short / useless answers

Tags: address-sanitizer

What do I do when program compiled with `-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -ggdb -O1` and linked with `-lasan`. Gives me these types of answers:

```
==87195==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 71895 byte(s) in 582 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fe4cf8defef in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:69
    #1 0x7fe4cea6c948 in g_malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0+0x5f948) (BuildId: 88d7a1c8d79fc1becb2737be566dd98523394d55)

Direct leak of 6656 byte(s) in 26 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fe4cf8defef in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:69
    #1 0x7fe4ce730a01  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1+0x20a01) (BuildId: 68b386df3452bdfc273639549ced62f4284745b9)
```

As far as I can see, they are almost useless.

I have tried this with both gcc and clang. Set `llvm-symbolizer` path (to `llvm-symbolizer-15`, there were several available). Using libasan.so.8 and tried

```
gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0
```

and

```
Ubuntu clang version 15.0.7
```

Shouldn't I at least get to see which of my functions did the allocation, maybe even a source line number?

Answer (score 2):

The leak happens in system libraries (libglib-2.0.so.0 and libfontconfig.so) which were not compiled with Asan-friendly flags (`-g -fno-omit-frame-pointer`) so Asan fails to collect stack trace across them. Running with `export ASAN_OPTIONS=fast_unwind_on_malloc=false` might help.

As a side note instead of using `-lasan` we should use `-fsanitize=address` in linker flags (see [this comment](https://groups.google.com/g/address-sanitizer/c/SD590XDinfQ/m/NMUPj_G0BgAJ) from Asan developers).